# is there a way to give date dropdown in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to add a date dropdown option in Quicksight but unable to select the date option while creating a parameter. need your help here

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Go to Parameters. Start a new parameter and then choose the Date/Time type
[image: Screenshot]